# Parsing and creating a Infinite/indefinite level of List/sublist from a XML in Android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

In my `Android Application` whose server side App is also getting developed by me. In this app android app request some `XML` from server and parse it. The `XML` contains the information that describes how much tab should be in the app and each tab have a `ListView` while each list item can navigate to another `Activity` which may also result in another sub `ListView` this level is infinite.
`XML` that I am generating from server is of this type.

```
<Application>
    <Tabs>
         <Tab id="1" tabtitle="Info">
              <ListItems>
                   <ListItem id="1" itemtype="list" itemtitle="1.1" itemdata="Issue1,Issue2,Issue3,Issue4,Issue 5">
                   </ListItem>
                    <ListItem id="3" itemtype="list" itemtitle="1.2" itemdata="News Links">
                    </ListItem>
                     <ListItem id="5" itemtype="list" itemtitle="1.3" itemdata="sampleDataURL type">
                         <ListItems>
                             <ListItem id="1" itemtype="list" itemtitle="1.3.1" itemdata="some data">
                              </ListItem>
                              <ListItem id="3" itemtype="list" itemtitle="1.3.2" itemdata="some data">
                                   <ListItems>
                                         <ListItem id="1" itemtype="list" itemtitle="1.3.2.1" itemdata="Issue1,Issue2,Issue3,Issue4,Issue 5">
                                          </ListItem>
                                          <ListItem id="3" itemtype="list" itemtitle="1.3.2.2" itemdata="News Links">
                                          </ListItem>
                                    </ListItems>
                                </ListItem>
                            </ListItems>
                        </ListItem> 
                  </ListItems>
             </Tab>
             <Tab id="2" tabtitle="More">   
                   <ListItems>
                   </ListItems>
              </Tab>
              <Tab id="3" tabtitle="Share"> 
                    <ListItems>
                    </ListItems>
              </Tab>
      </Tabs>
</Application>
```

As a result my my android can generate 3 tabs at runtime but please guide what type of code/logic should I compose to write it's `SAXParser` and what type of Model data should i populate in android App through parser.Should i go for `HashMap` rather than `ArrayList<CustomClass>`.

This is challenging for me to implement it efficiently and robustly.

Comment: Do you really have the memory or the time to parse an infinite list?

Comment: hey man list will never go beyond 4-5 level practically , but at the time of writing the code we cannot know how longer the list may be

Comment: You can use "ViewAnimator + tab view" to control your tab based design. this way, you will have to create 3 different activities which will work as the content of 3 tabs. In each activity, use ViewAnimator as outermost layout and add listviews to it as per your requirement.

For data structure, you can use either of hashmap OR arrayList.. but  in the end it finally depends on how efficiently you use them.

may be this helps..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this by introducing a new tag in the XML i.e. parentId in every list item for ListItems which are under tabs the parent id will b the id of that tab and in case of other sub list items the parentId will the id of the parent list item.

then I parse and store all tabs in one array list and all item in other arraylist
then on every activity i create a temp arraylist holding items useful for that activity only .I can filter out items from this list of items by comparing id of parent and parentId of child.

Comment: Can you also please share the code of parsing your xmls and how you are adding it in LView and sublists?

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you display things in tabs doesn't need to be part of the XML. You can also let one item contain other items.

```
<Application>
    <Items id="1" title="Info">
        <Item id="1" type="list" title="1.1" data="Issue1,Issue2,Issue3,Issue4,Issue 5" />
        <Item id="3" type="list" title="1.2" data="News Links" />
        <Item id="5" type="list" title="1.3" data="sampleDataURL type">
            <Item id="1" type="list" title="1.3.1" data="some data" />
            <Item id="3" type="list" title="1.3.2" data="some data">
                <Item id="1" type="list" title="1.3.2.1" data="Issue1,Issue2,Issue3,Issue4,Issue 5" />
                <Item id="3" type="list" title="1.3.2.2" data="News Links" />
            </Item> 
        </Item> 
    </Items>
    <Items id="2" title="More">
    </Items>
    <Items id="3" title="Share">
    </Items>
</Application>
```

Whether you use this structure or not, you can create a similar structure locally using a custom pojo Item class for Item and have each Item contain a field like...

```
public ArrayList<Item> mSubItems = new ArrayList<Item>();
```

...where you store the subitems. And create these objects during the SAX parsing.

If you want to pass the items from activity to activity, it's probably easier to use a Bundle objects directly instead of custom Item class.